# Getting lag by creating Unity Meshes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

In Unity3D, I created this sort of prediction path for some kind of missile in 3D. First I was just using line render, until I quickly realized it was very limiting. So I switched to drawing my own meshes and it's rather beautiful. I just have one problem. In the scene when I'm running the drawMesh function everything runs quickly, but as soon as I switch to another scene there's about a 2 second lag and then everything resumes as normal. Line render didn't present any lag whatsoever, so I must have messed something up because drawing your own meshes should be more efficient.

I suspect somehow when creating my meshes the old ones never get delete, therefore when I change the scene it takes a bit to clear them all away. I'd expect the garbage collector to take care of this, but I'm probably setting something up slightly wrong. The longer you stay in the scene the longer the lag is so that's where my suspicion arises. This is just speculation though.

If anyone could take a look at my code and suggest a fix I'd appreciate it greatly.

Here's the code. It's a little complicated, but not much can be done about that. I'll include the area of code that I think is the culprit because the same code with line render worked. It runs about 30 times per frame.

```
void drawMesh(Vector3[] vertices, Material m)
     {
         var mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

         var mesh = new Mesh();
         mf.mesh = mesh;

         mesh.vertices = vertices;

         var tris = new int[6]
         {
             // lower left triangle
             0, 2, 1,
             // upper right triangle
             2, 3, 1
         };
         mesh.triangles = tris;

         var normals = new Vector3[4]
         {
             -Vector3.forward,
             -Vector3.forward,
             -Vector3.forward,
             -Vector3.forward
         };
         mesh.normals = normals;

         var uv = new Vector2[4]
         {
             new Vector2(0, 0),
             new Vector2(1, 0),
             new Vector2(0, 1),
             new Vector2(1, 1)
         };
         mesh.uv = uv;
         Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, m, 0, null, 0, null, false, false);
     }
 }
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Unity garbage collector has a problem.  I had to make sure I was manually deleting the meshes after they were created.  I put them in an array of length (however long you want them to exist for) and then delete old elements once they exceeded then length.